# Why isn't my StatusBar updating while I do work?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm, statusbar

I want to add a statusbar to my application but I can't figure out what the best solution will be? I am using c# with WPF and the model MVVM.

Right now I have a solution which partly work. The problem is that the status bar isn't updating as often as I would like it to.
When I eg write a new value to the string that the status bar is bound to, the status bar will update too late and want show any diffrences.

## A simple example (not real code):

StatusBar is bound to status and is initialy = Ready.

1. status = Downloading
2. download method
3. status = Ready

This results in no visual change. When I debug the code the value of status is updated but isn't changed in the statusbar.

Do you have any sugestions?

## My Code

### XAML View: MainView.xaml

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
        <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0 -5 0 0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>

        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Name="statusBarStatus" Text="{Binding Status}"></TextBlock>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
```

### Part of MainViewModel

```
private void UpdateDepartmentsExecute()
    {
        Status = "Updating...";

        repository.ShowAppDep = ShowAppDep;
        repository.ShowInDep = ShowInDep;
        repository.ShowSisDep = ShowSisDep;

        repository.getPriority1 = SetPriorityTo1;
        repository.getPriority2 = SetPriorityTo2;
        repository.getPriority3 = SetPriorityTo3;
        repository.getPriority4 = SetPriorityTo4;
        repository.getPriority5 = SetPriorityTo5;

        repository.UpdateTasksToShow();
        repository.UpdateWorkareas();
        repository.UpdateEmployees();
        repository.UpdateTasksToShowByEmployee();
        repository.UpdateWorkAreaByEmployee();
        repository.GenerateStatistics();

        TasksToShowCount = repository.TasksToShow.Count();

        if (SelectedView == new Uri("pack://application:,,,/View/EstimateLoadView.xaml"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Gantt Chart wan't show all relations when you are filtering the data. This might be a source to errors.", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            SelectedView = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/View/EntryView.xaml");
        }

        Status = "Ready";        }
```

Comment: Could you post your view and view model code

Comment: I agree with devdigital. Please post the class or at least the property you are binding to.
I have used a statusbar with MVVM and a converter and never had any issues with it.
I assume your INotifyPropertyChanged could be invalid or your app is  so busy that the UI Thread is not able to catch up refreshing the UI which could result from threaded operations.

Comment: Who needs code?  He's doing everything on the UI thread, blocking updates to the bar until after he's done.

Comment: So will it work if I implement multithreading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You MUST do your download in a background thread, the easiest way would be using a BackgroundWorker component.  Otherwise your download is happening in the UI thread, which means your blocking message pumping and repainting.  Blocking that means you're UI doesn't update, and worse can mean Windows thinks your application is not responding.

To update your collection bound to the UI thread, you should be able to use the ReportProgress event and pass some data, which the handler can then use to update the OC.  The ReportProgress handler will be marsheled to the proper UI thread.

Comment: Okay... go it so far. The only catch is that the download method is editing in an ObervalCollection which I am binding to in the UI. So it want let me do the changes. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use a dispatcher from your Background Thread (assuming you are running the status update in one!). Here's a good blog post: [Updating UI from a background thread](http://weblogs.asp.net/cschittko/archive/2008/05/14/wpf-ui-update-from-background-threads.aspx)

Comment: I would like to do so, but I am not at the moment. In the example you send me I don't know how to do this part: runner.RequestFinished. I cant find anythink called RequestFinished?

Comment: And one more thing. How do I call my methods provided by the ModelView from the code behind? This seams to be very important if I want to create a background thread because I only can call begin invoke from the code behind. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The example uses an event handler method (which subscribes to a event named RequestFinished), but in your case you could make the BeginInvoke call from some other method. For example, the method that you use to update the statuses (again, assuming that you are running it in a background thread!)

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind to  `Properties.Settings.Default`. In sence, that if you want that DataBinding works, you should bind to a property of a class that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), in your case.

On the same linked page you should see also an example, of how to do that.

Add to this also, like Lauri suggested, non UI blocking calls, in order to give your UI a possiblity to "breath".

Comment: Now I have added a new variable to my repository `private string status = "Loading...";
        public string Status
        {
            get { return status; }
            set
            {
                status = value;
                Notify("Status");
            }
        }` and edited the binding in the View into this `<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock Name="statusBarStatus" Text="{Binding Status}"></TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>` and my viewmodel has got this variable which i am editing whenever I want to change the status message.

Comment: `public string Status
        {
            get { return repository.Status; }

            set { repository.Status = value; }
        }` It is getting the value when the application starts, but isn't getting any updates????

Comment: Just moved the Notify into my ViewModel and now it partly works again. It is getting the change in status message, but only the last of them. Not the one comming in the beginning of the code.

Comment: You see only "Ready", so final result, only because you block UI in your "long running operation". Run that operation on other thread, and you will see texts yuo want appearing on Statusbar. Obviously you need to tune the work of different thread with main UI thread.